# mailto: link not working using play framework in scala.html

Tags: javascript, html, scala, playframework-2.0

```
<a href="mailto:support@abc.com"> mail me </a>
```

Above code does not work because The @-symbol in mailto makes the framework cry for a value since it thinks that @ is a scala-command. Thus, to escape the @-symbol I used double @@ which works in simple texts.

But in above link when I used like this:

```
<a href="mailto:support@@abc.com"> Mail me </a>
```

here, mailto: is not working.

Comment: Why do you need the `[...]`? Can't you simply do `mailto:support@abc.com` since the value is just hardcoded?

Comment: that I have put by mistake, I am simply using it as edited in question. Thanks

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `scala`, but can you try `@'mailto:support@abc.com'`? Or how you would point out it's a text in the framework.

Answer (score 2):

You need put `@` twice, like `support@@abc.com`

I did verification on my own twirl template

```
<a href="mailto:support@@abc.com"> Mail me </a>
```

Is perfectly work. Maybe you cached a wrong version?